# Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string

Tags: javascript

This is my .js file:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import multer from "multer";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
// Below comes with node so we didn't install it.
import path from "path";  
import { fileURLToPath } from "url"; 
// These Two are used to setup paths when we are using directories. 


/*CONFIGURATIONS
These will include middleware config as well as package config*/
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({policy:"cross-origin"}));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "30mb", extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:"30mb", extended:true}));
app.use(cors()) //Cross Orign Resource Policies. 
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets')));
//The above line does is it sets dir where we keep our assets. In our cse we do it locally. In actual case we do it in a proper storage system 

/*FILE STORAGE */
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : function(req, file, cb){      
        cb(null, "public/assests");
    },
    //When someone uploads a photo into the wpage, it's gonna save in the public/assets folder. 
    filename : function(req, file, cb ){
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage});
//This will help us save the img. Anytime we are going to upload a file we use the variable upload. 

//Go to mongoDB website and create a datbase cluster. 
//.env file is created. 

/*MONGOOSE SETUP */


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser : true,
    useUnifiedTopology : true,
}).then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port : ${PORT}`));
}).catch((error) => console.log( `${error} did not connect`))
```

This is my .env file:

```
MONGO_URL = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.nbhppgf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
PORT = 3001
```

Error i am facing is :
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string. did not connect

Plz help me.

I want the output to print the port number.

Comment: I think `process.env.MONGO_URL`, is an empty string, try logging that. Now to make this work, is your .env file in the same directory as your .js file?

Comment: Yes, .env is in the same directory as .js file.

Comment: try removing the spaces around  `=` in the .env file

Comment: did that. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try `import dotenv/config` at the top, instead of the current import you have.
This is the correct way per the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv?activeTab=readme#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import

Comment: I did that. The error isn't changing. I think there is some sort of conversion problem from my .env file. It is saying that my first parameter is not a string. But in my .env file i gave the url as a sting. I tried using toString() to convert it into string but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: I think the issue is that your env variable isnt read. A console.log should tell you...

Comment: You can aslo try using require import instead of es6 import. However the es6 import should already work, but maybe do this for sanity check...

Comment: I didn't understand. Can u explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue few months back and solved it by changing `.env` to `.parsed`.

I've just checked `dotenv` package source code and couldn't see `.env` functionality. So, it might be officially replaced by `.parsed`.

So, you might just need to do the following in your code:

```js
// import dotenv and call config function
// if you don't call config() `.parsed` property will not be accessible
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
const process = dotenv.config();

// then change
process.env.MONGO_URL
// to
process.parsed.MONGO_URL
```

---

For testing:

- Create `.env` file in project root, and add `TOKEN=MYTOKEN`.
- Install `dotenv` package (npm i dotenv).
- Paste below code in `index.js` file.

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
const process = dotenv.config();
console.log(process.parsed.TOKEN)
```

- Run code `node index.js`

`MYTOKEN` should be logged in the console.

Comment: After doing that it's saying 
"TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MONGO_URL')"

Comment: try to call `config()` first. I've updated the answer accordingly. Please note that there was a typo. I meant `parsed` not `parse`.

Comment: Now it's giving me this error:
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead

Comment: I tought you are aware about the difference between CommonJS and ES. The code was written as CommonJS and your environment supports ES. I've updated the answer to support ES.

Comment: My bad. I am actually new to JavaScript. I have changed the code. It says that i have a type error. 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PORT')

Comment: If you notice that `PORT` is still using `.env` which is not exist anymore. So you need to change all `.env` to `.parsed`.

Comment: I changed that one also. This is the error i got after changing both the .env
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PORT')

Comment: Try to hardcode `PORT` value temporarily to any static number and verify `.parsed` is working. Then, you might update your code to investigate further.

Comment: it would be appreciated to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I am really sorry man. I was busy with some other work and didn't check this one. As I said I am a beginner to Js. I need to learn more about this. I'll come back after gaining enough knowledge. Thx for the help. Really appreciate it.