# Can't access env file with jwt constants.ts

Tags: javascript, jwt, nestjs

I have a project and I need to implement JWT service. I have followed the nest.js docs for this.
In the file constants.ts I export an object that has a secret for key and my process.env for value

```
export const jwtConstants = () => ({
  secret: process.env.SECRET_JWT,
});
```

and this doesn't work.
I have tried with a key directly in value and that works.
I don't know why I can't access my env file in this file.
This is my auth module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User, UserSchema } from '../user/user.schema';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, UserService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

my auth service

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { AuthDto } from './dto/auth.dto';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import * as argon2 from 'argon2';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async signIn(authDto: AuthDto): Promise<{ access_token: string }> {
    const user = await this.userService.findOne(authDto.email);
    try {
      if (await argon2.verify(user.password, authDto.password)) {
        const payload = {
          userName: user.firstName,
          userLastName: user.lastName,
          userPhone: user.phone,
          userEmail: user.email,
        };
        return {
          access_token: await this.jwtService.signAsync(payload),
        };
      } else {
        console.log('doesn\t match');
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log('doesn\t work');
    }
  }
}
```

and my app module with the ConfigModule.forRoot

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { CompanyModule } from './company/company.module';
import { CallForBidsModule } from './callForBids/call-for-bids.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { User, UserSchema } from './user/user.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_DB_URL, {
      dbName: process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE_NAME,
      auth: {
        username: process.env.MONGO_DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD,
      },
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    // feature module
    UserModule,
    CompanyModule,
    CallForBidsModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have tried changing the lib and added the dotenv lib for Nestjs but got the same result.
I have tried with the key directly that worked but I need to use the .envfile
Rebuild the project doesn't work either.

Comment: try to use `.parse` instead of `.env`. Refer to my post for more explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77894012/make-sure-the-first-parameter-to-mongoose-connect-or-mongoose-createconnect/77894068#77894068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current `jwtConstants` you should be accessing the secret like `jwtConstants().secret` as it's a function export.

However, as you're using `@nestjs/config`, the better approach would be to use `JwtModule.registerAsync` and inject the `ConfigService` to the `JwtModule` rather than relying on `process.env`, so ensure that the values are coming from where you think they are. This would look something like

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User, UserSchema } from '../user/user.schema';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    JwtModule.registerAsync(
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
        global: true,
        secret: config.get('SECRET_JWT'),
        signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, UserService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

You can also do a similar approach with your `MongooseModule` using a `forRootAsync` to inject the `ConfigService` and get the env variables from there

Comment: Thank you for this response. It works perfectly! I followed your advice and made the correction in my MongooseModule